# Is it safe to delete the stage directory?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic11g

One of my servers is running out of capacity, mostly due to WebLogic's stage folder. I've been looking for information and it seems to be a temporal folder, but unlike older versions, on WL11g this folder is out of the tmp folder. So I'm not sure whether or not I can safely remove it.

Comment: Why don't you try removing it on a live test instance?

Answer (score 3):

Stage directory is where weblogic copies all the applications that it needs to deploy on to the managed servers. Wls does not delete any file from this folder. So in the long run if you have done deployment of many versions of your application then this folder can become rather large.

So yes you can delete the contents of this folder. At the time of restart wls will copy all the necessary files to this folder (this could take some time).

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can delete the stage. All the necessary applications details will be there in this directory, but any how if it is a large environment(many applications are running), just take the back up of the directory or rename it and then you can safely delete the stage.