# WebLogic 12c - Difference Between Stage Directory and Upload

Tags: oracle, weblogic12c

I uploaded a new ear file to WebLogic 12c. I then issued the *nix `find` command that outputs the md5sums of the files that the search finds. I noticed that there are two different versions of the ear I uploaded.

I know that one of the md5sums is a sum for the previous version of the ear file and the other md5sum is for the latest version of the file. I saw that the previous version is in a folder under a directory called `stage`. The latest version is under a folder called `AdminServer`. Please see the output of the find command below that shows this:

> [me@corp-box ~]$ find /app -name CORP_UI.ear -exec md5sum "{}" \;
>   0d03c0bf96b3f700da5c44454a66ace8 
>   /app/oracle/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/die_domain/servers/CORP/stage/CORP_UI/CORP_UI.ear
>   649f5c222e014fb7af05178e13cab708 
>   /app/oracle/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/die_domain/servers/AdminServer/upload/CORP/app/CORP_UI.ear
>   md5sum:
>   /app/oracle/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/die_domain/config/deployments/CORP_UI.ear: Is a directory [me@corp-box ~]$

I saw a question pertaining to the stage folder at the following URL: [Is it safe to delete the stage directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21597767/is-it-safe-to-delete-the-stage-directory)

I am wondering what the stage directory is? Is this where applications go to die? Why would the previous version of the application be in the stage directory and the new copy under the **../AdminServer/upload/..** directory?

Comment: HI! Didn't vote your question because I think it it quite clear and concise, so it will get precise answers :)
And yes, I formatted your log because it helps others by coloring commands. We can try to make it a quote so you feel more confortable. Either case, you don't need to be rude to make a point.

Comment: Oh, sorry if that sounded rude, especially if you did not vote to close my interesting question. I thought it was rude that someone voted to close my question.Thank-you @Alfabravo for formatting the shell "code" showing the find command. I like what you did here. The scroll bars can be annoying but maybe it can be more readable for some or in some situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to oracle documentation, the Upload directory is:

"The directory path on the Administration Server where all uploaded applications are placed."

the Stage directory is:

"The directory path on the Managed Server where all staged (prepared) applications are placed."

The stage directory can be deleted after stopping the managed servers.
As a matter of fact you can delete the whole directories /servers/ and their content. Whenever you restart the managed servers they are recreated by weblogic. Just pay attention not to delete the admin server directory!

Comment: Thank-you for the helpful answer. I was wondering why when I upload an application with WLST the uploaded application ends up under the "upload" directory and the previous version of the application remains under the "stage" directory.